# Resolving class inheritance algorithm

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, sorting, recursion

I have a list of pairs with class inheritance information like this

```
[
  [Person, null],
  [Person, SpecialPerson], // Person extends SpecialPerson
  [SpecialPerson, VerySpecialPerson], // SpecialPerson extends VerySpecialPerson
]
```

Is there any particular algorithm to *flatten* this information?

Like this:

> Person -> SpecialPerson -> VerySpecialPerson

Comment: Shouldn't first line be `[null, Person]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it boils down to a DAG (directed acyclic graph). Therefore you would do a breadth-first search or depth-first search. You only need the simplified case for trees.

Example (BFS, pseudo-code, untested):

```
List<Array<Typespec>> flatten(Array<Pair<Typespec,Typespec>> input) {
  List<Array<Typespec>> result;
  Queue<Array<Typespec>*> q;

  var elem=&result.append([null]);
  q.append(elem);
  while (!q.empty()) {
    for (i in input) {
      if (i.first==q.front().back()) {
        var elem=&result.append(q.front().clone().append(i.second));
        q.append(elem);
      }
    }
    q.pop_front();
  }
  return result;
}
```

This assumes that you meant `[null,Person]`, instead of the other way round. Note that it produces a `null` at the start of every result, differing from your example.